# How to connect with local port and gateway host?

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL(~1week),

I'm trying to connect with a database that Has:

- Local port number
- gateway host
- db user
- db port
- db

How can I include that local port and gateway host?
And do I need to?

Currently i'm using the following command line without luck:

```sh
mysql --port=db port -h dbhost-u db user -p db
```

I'm getting: `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on dbhost`

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You need a space before `-u`. Is that just a typo in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using that command exactly as you have typed it? It's hard to tell. If you have, then you need to change the values to real ones.

You can omit the port if you have not changed it from default when installing MySQL.

You need to replace "dbhost" with "localhost", "dbuser" with "root" which is the MySQL equivalent of an admin account. You can leave out the database name as its not required to log in.

Comment: No this is just an example, let me try your suggestions, thanks

Comment: If you get stuck, I can help you write the exact command once establish a few details.

Comment: I turns out I need to SSH to their database, thanks for your help

Comment: Ah so it's not your local database - it's a remote database then. The command line will be the same, but you need to obviously log in to the remote server via SSH first. That will be why it wouldn't connect, because you need to use the command line on a remote server instead. Best of luck with it.